DNS- Setting up website with my registered domain name
I have a registered domain name with Netfirms. I am hosting a website on Github. How do I point the domain name to my website on Github. I was given a long URL from Github where I can see my website. I want to use the one that I registered with Netfirms to point to the URL for Github. I can change the nameservers on the Netfirms site but I think I need to modify the DNS records on the nameservers themselves. Do I have to access the nameservers to make these changes? I am not sure even how to access them. Do I have to modify the A record? That only takes an IP address where I need to put the Github URL ?
I logged into Netfirms and can modify the nameservers but I am unsure where to make the DNS record updates to point to my new website


Do I have to access the nameservers to make these changes?

To some extent, that's up to you, because you have access to change the nameservers – so the first step would be to change them to ones which grant you access to make changes.

If the registrar offers you to use their own nameservers (many registrars provide free DNS hosting service), then they will certainly have a "DNS control panel" somewhere in their website, that you can use to make these changes – otherwise there would be little point in them providing a nameserver at all.

In case the registrar does not offer DNS hosting (e.g. they only provide "placeholder" nameservers), then it's up to you to find a place that does. The nameserver host doesn't need to be related to your website nor your domain. These days people often use CloudFlare or Route53 or similar cloud providers; all of them provide DNS as a service.


In your case, I found a Netfirms documentation page showing that the place to change DNS records on the Netfirms nameserver should be next to the same place where you change nameserver addresses themselves:

